# Configuration root() calls a deprecated method

Tags: playframework

Calling play.Configuration.root() calls

play.api.Play.unsafeApplication().configuration() which is deprecated.

Not sure if this is related to the issue I'm encountering, but this occurs when running the server in production mode, a hibernate persistent class that grabs variables from the application.conf receives null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Java or Scala? If you're using a somewhat recent version, you should inject the configuration.

Comment: Using java. Upgrading to Play 2.5

Comment: How about using dependency injection to obtain an instance of Configuration?